# Index OutOfBound Exception for a piece of code?

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to run the code below but I'm getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I know where the problem is but in order to improve the code, I want to add an `if` statement, such that the `while` loop breaks if the index is out of bounds.  It should now print `"bcd"` without throwing an exception.

Believe that an if statement should be used for this: `index > input.length() - 3` but where do I add it?

```
public class test {
    public void findAbc(String input) {
        int index = input.indexOf("abc");
        while (true) {
            if (index == -1) {
                break;
            }

            String found = input.substring(index + 1, index + 4);
            System.out.println(found);
            index = input.indexOf("abc", index + 4);


        }
    }

    public void test() {
        findAbc("abcdabc");
    }
}
```

Comment: **It should now print "bcd"** here d means next character after 'c'

Comment: What is the purpose of this method, and why do you hard code `abc` as a substring?

Comment: now well indented

Comment: but i don't understand, when you found `abc` why are printing `bcd`, one character ahead. if you trying to find all the appearance of `abc` in your string it won't give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this condition in your `while-loop` condition,

```
while (index < input.length()-3 && index >= 0) { }
```